# Exclude regression constant from non-linear regression

Tags: regression

For example, suppose I've data set and I want to perform a non-linear regression on the data set as follows:

$Y=B_1e^{B_2 X} + B_3$

and I found that if I exclude $B_3$ the $R^2$ increased also standard error of the regression decreased, can I exclude $B_3$?

Comment: See this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/80822/71442

Comment: the suggested answers are for linear regression but I mean non-linear regression

Comment: what method exactly?

Comment: Curve estimating

Comment: Reading the other question and answer, it looks like the answer also solves your question...

Comment: thank all but it is not solve because I mean non-linear regression not linear regression