# For a linear model without intercept, why does the redundent term in one-hot encoding function as intercept?

Tags: linear-regression

In [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27957/why-do-we-need-to-discard-one-dummy-variable/27993#27993?newreg=78d94308734649308c87ec6554fe057b) Elias Strehle pointed out that if we keep all the levels during one hot encoding on a linear model without an intercept, the redundant feature will function as an intercept. Why is this the case?

Isn't that in a linear model, the intercept term ($x_0$, not $\beta_0$) will always have a value of 1? Suppose the feature to encode is gender, then some of the rows of the redundant term will be 0 while others will be 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look how dummies work:

**R Example:**

```
# Some data
df = data.frame(y=c(30,32,28,10,11,9),gender=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), gender2=c(0,0,0,1,1,1))

# 1) Regression with constant and dummy
summary(lm(y~gender,data=df))

# 2) Regression without constant and dummy
summary(lm(y~gender-1,data=df))

# 3) Regression without constant and two dummies
summary(lm(y~gender+gender2-1,data=df))
```

**Results:**

**Case 1:**
Since dummies generally work as "contrasts" to some base category (1 vs. 0 / "on" vs. "off") and since the base category has a mean of 10, the intercept term equals 10 and for `gender = 1`, the difference to the base category is identified (here 20) because the mean of category `gender = 1` is 30. (Remember that a regression with only an intercept or with dummies simply gives the arithmetic mean).

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.0000     0.9129   10.95 0.000394 ***
gender       20.0000     1.2910   15.49 0.000101 ***
```

**Case 2:**
Without a constant only `gender = 1` is considered, since for `gender = 0` we have $0 + 0 * \beta$ so that `gender = 0` is dropped. The coefficient now is the mean of `gender = 1`.

```
Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
gender   30.000      4.546   6.599   0.0012 **
```

**Case 3:**
Including a dummy for both groups (denote `gender = 0` from above as `gender2`) without adding an intercept now gives the mean for each group directly. Note that the interpretation of the coefficients is different here compared to case 1.

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
gender   30.0000     0.9129   32.86 5.11e-06 ***
gender2  10.0000     0.9129   10.95 0.000394 ***
```

**The interesting bit is when you add some additional $x$:**

Some new data, now including $x$:

```
df = data.frame(y=c(30,32,28,10,11,9),gender=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), gender2=c(0,0,0,1,1,1), x=c(20,22,25,28,30,29))
```

**Regression with both dummies, no intercept:**

```
summary(lm(y~gender2+gender-1+x,data=df))

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
gender2  19.8864    12.6285   1.575   0.2134  
gender   37.6136     9.7446   3.860   0.0307 *
x        -0.3409     0.4342  -0.785   0.4897
```

is the same as...

**Regression with one dummy and intercept (apart of the dummy interpretation discused above):**

```
summary(lm(y~gender+x,data=df))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  19.8864    12.6285   1.575   0.2134  
gender       17.7273     3.1973   5.544   0.0116 *
x            -0.3409     0.4342  -0.785   0.4897
```

... so the marginal effect of $x$ is the same. This is in contrast to...

**Regression with one dummy, no intercept:**

```
summary(lm(y~gender+x-1,data=df))

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
gender 22.38736    1.41677  15.802 9.37e-05 ***
x       0.34086    0.03864   8.822 0.000911 ***
```

Here the marginal effect of $x$ is entirely different.

**Why is this?**

When you fit some new data, you will see that the fitted line for $x$ goes through (0,0) "no intercept in the model".

```
newdata = data.frame(gender=c(0,0,0,0,0,0), x=c(-1,0,1,2,3,4))
predict(lm(y~gender+x-1,data=df), newdata=newdata)

         1          2          3          4          5          6 
-0.3408643  0.0000000  0.3408643  0.6817286  1.0225929  1.3634572
```

This happens because there are cases in which you have $0 + \beta x$ (which is 0 for $x=0$). Or as $x$-matrix (first row would be the intercept, for illustration = 0):

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & x_1\\
0 & 1 & x_2\\
0 & 0 & x_3\\
0 & 0 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}

However, when you have the two dummies included, you have:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & x_1\\
0 & 1 & x_2\\
1 & 0 & x_3\\
1 & 0 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}

So there is no case in which you force $\beta x$ to be zero.

See [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/80822/71442) for further discussion on regression without constant term.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter!! Very clear!